# R Remove rows if value in one column appears again in another column without loop

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I would like to remove cases where the combination of two columns also appears as a reverse combination in those two same columns

Below is the input and desired output.

[image: SS of Tables]

It doesn't matter if the first or second occurrence is kept.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "x1" = 1:6, 
  "x2" = c(2,1,4,3,6,5), 
  "x3" = c("a","b", "c","d","e","f"))
```

Comment: Can you please share your example input in a format I can copy/paste in to R? Images are a very unfriendly way to share data. `dput(your_input)` or `dput(head(you_input))` is an easy way to make a copy/pasteable R object.

Comment: `nopes = unname(as.list(DT[, 2:1])); res = DT[!nopes, on=names(DT)[1:2]]`? Not sure if it works since there's no example to test with.

Comment: Sure, Try this: df <- data.frame("x1" = 1:6, "x2" = c(2,1,4,3,6,5), "x3" = c("a","b", "c","d","e","f"))

Comment: with that data, you can do `subset(df,!duplicated(t(apply(df[-3],1,sort))))`

Comment: `df[!duplicated(t(apply(df[-3],1,sort))),]`

Comment: Excellent. That worked! Thanks Onyambu.

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion worked just fine for me:

```
subset(df,!duplicated(t(apply(df[-3],1,sort))))
```